# Heroku not running MongoDB functions

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, heroku

On two of my apps now I've been able to run my mongoDB functions successfully however, the deployed version on Heroku does not update my DBs, despite in the logs showing being connected. [heroku logs here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wszbM.png)

I've ensured that I have added the MONGODB_URL as a config variable in the Heroku settings. Otherwise it wouldn't show it connected to the DB. Below is one example of an endpoint.

```
app.get('/update/:entry', async (req, res) => {
    let entryArray = []
    const basicInfo = await axios.get(`https://api.opensea.io/api/v1/collection/${req.params.entry}`)
    const name = basicInfo.data.collection.name.toString()
    const slug = basicInfo.data.collection.slug.toString()
    const symbol = basicInfo.data.collection.primary_asset_contracts[0]?.symbol?.toString() || ''
    const description = basicInfo.data.collection.description?.toString() || ''
    const verifiedStatus = basicInfo.data.collection.safelistRequestStatus?.toString() || ''
    const bannerUrl = basicInfo.data.collection.banner_image_url?.toString() || ''
    const logoUrl = basicInfo.data.collection.image_url?.toString() || ''
    const stats = {
        one_day_volume: basicInfo.data.collection.stats.one_day_volume,
        one_day_change: basicInfo.data.collection.stats.one_day_change,
        one_day_sales: basicInfo.data.collection.stats.one_day_sales,
        one_day_average_price: basicInfo.data.collection.stats.one_day_average_price,
        seven_day_volume: basicInfo.data.collection.stats.seven_day_volume,
        seven_day_change: basicInfo.data.collection.stats.seven_day_change,
        seven_day_sales: basicInfo.data.collection.stats.seven_day_sales,
        seven_day_average_price: basicInfo.data.collection.stats.seven_day_average_price,
        thirty_day_volume: basicInfo.data.collection.stats.thirty_day_volume,
        thirty_day_change: basicInfo.data.collection.stats.thirty_day_change,
        thirty_day_sales: basicInfo.data.collection.stats.thirty_day_sales,
        thirty_day_average_price: basicInfo.data.collection.stats.thirty_day_average_price,
        total_volume: basicInfo.data.collection.stats.total_volume,
        total_sales: basicInfo.data.collection.stats.total_sales,
        total_supply: basicInfo.data.collection.stats.total_supply,
        count: basicInfo.data.collection.stats.count,
        average_price: basicInfo.data.collection.stats.average_price,
        num_reports: basicInfo.data.collection.stats.num_reports,
        market_cap: basicInfo.data.collection.stats.market_cap,
    }
    const social = {
        discord: basicInfo.data.collection.discord_url?.toString() || '',
        medium: basicInfo.data.collection.medium_username?.toString() || '',
        twitter: basicInfo.data.collection.twitter_username?.toString() || '',
        instagram: basicInfo.data.collection.instagram_username?.toString() || '',
        wiki: basicInfo.data.collection.wiki_url?.toString() || ''
    }

    let floorPrice = 0
    if (basicInfo.data.collection.stats.floor_price == null) {
        floorPrice = 0
    } else {
        floorPrice = basicInfo.data.collection.stats.floor_price
    }

    entryArray.push({"name":name, "slug":slug, "symbol":symbol, "description":description, "isVerified":verifiedStatus, "banner":bannerUrl, "logo":logoUrl, "floorPrice":floorPrice, "stats":stats, "socials":social})

    NFT.findOne({ "name": name }, async (err, value) => {
        if (err) { console.error(err) }
        if (!value) {
            const newNFT = new NFT({"name":name, "slug":slug, "symbol":symbol, "description":description, "isVerified":verifiedStatus, "banner":bannerUrl, "logo":logoUrl, "floorPrice":floorPrice, "stats":stats, "socials":social})
            await newNFT.save()
        } 
        else {
                // Update existing NFT
                value.name = name 
                value.slug = slug
                value.symbol = symbol
                value.description = description
                value.verifiedStatus = verifiedStatus
                value.bannerUrl = bannerUrl
                value.logoUrl = logoUrl
                value.floorPrice = floorPrice
                value.stats = stats
                value.social = social
                await value.save();
        }
    })
    res.json(entryArray)
})
```

***Edit***  After some troubleshooting I have determined that on the Heroku side if you add ""s around the MONGODB_URI or in my case URL you get an error saying it expects the URI to begin with a certain format. I have since stopped any an all crashes or error messages, but it still is not updating my DB.

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't update your DB, do you get an error or do you just not see a difference?

Comment: @AaronMeese No error, but if I use the same query or attempt to push the same information it works locally but not deployed

Comment: @AaronMeese it seems that I needed to put ""'s around my heroku side MONGODB_URL variable but now they are all timing out.

Comment: Are you sure there is no firewall blocking incoming/outgoing connections?

Comment: @AaronMeese I can't be sure of that, because it's being run from Heroku

Answer (score 0):

Did you try all the steps which mention in below linked doc ?
Doc link:- [Setup MongoDB on HEROKU](https://www.mongodb.com/developer/products/atlas/use-atlas-on-heroku/)

Comment: Yes, I have 0.0.0.0/0 whitelisted, I'm connecting via process.env.MONGODB_URL which is listed as a variable on my heroku deployment too.